# Getting unusual sign (>>) throughout Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

Below is the snapshot of the unusual sign that I'm getting throughout Eclipse. However, it is not obstructing the normal flow of the program. Restarting Eclipse doesn't seem to solve the purpose.

**Any help would be highly appreciated.**

Comment: I don't have Eclipse for Ubuntu, so I can't check this, but see if there is a setting named "show invisibles". That's probably ticked and now it's showing you all the tabs and newlines. Disable to hide the invisible characters.

Comment: really hard to find it in a screensh....
wich line is it?

Comment: @jipr311 - It's throughout Eclipse. Not pertaining to a single line.

Comment: @Arc676 - where do I find the "Show invisible" link ?

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> "Show whitespace characters" on Eclipse Mars

Comment: I don't actually know. As I said, I don't have Ubuntu. And finding documentation for less-used OSs is hard. Look through the settings.

Comment: @Matt - that worked like a beauty.... If you could now post the same as an answer, I could then possibly close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the settings named "Show whitespace characters", located on Window -> Preference -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors.

Enabling it displays that characters in place of a tab. Disabling it hides those characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your text editor settings.
under

`Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors`.

There is a checkbox labeled "Show whitespace characters". If you uncheck this the editor switches back to normal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you prompt response. The error is gone !!!!